Series expansion of incomplete gamma function with two variables
I am working on finding the asymptotic expansion of the following integral, where $i$ is a positive integer and $y$ is a positive real number:
$$
I(i, y) = \int_0^y e^{-ix} (x+1)^{i-1} \, dx.
$$
This expression can be rewritten in terms of the incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(a, z)$ as:
$$
I(i, y) = e^i i^{-i} \left( \Gamma(i, i) - \Gamma(i, i(y+1)) \right),
$$
where $\Gamma(a, z)$ is the incomplete gamma function:
$$
\Gamma(a, z) = \int_z^\infty t^{a-1} e^{-t} \, dt.
$$
I am interested in finding the asymptotic expansion of this expression, expressed as a sum of rational functions in $i$ and $y$, with error terms of the form $O(i^m y^n)$ for some integers $m$ and $n$.
Using the series expansion of the incomplete gamma function from the DLMF, I derived the following result:
$$
e^i i^{-i} \left( \Gamma(i, i) - \Gamma(i, i(y+1)) \right) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{(i-1)! i^l \left( e^{-iy} (y+1)^{i+l} - 1 \right)}{(i+l)!}.
$$
However, this expression is difficult to use for my purpose. What I need is to express the original function as an infinite sum of rational functions of $i$ and $y$, and to determine the error terms when truncating the sum.
Is this possible? Are there general methods for dealing with similar integrals, such as
$$
I_2(i, y) = \int_0^y e^{-ix} \left( 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} \right)^{i-1} \, dx,
$$
and
$$
I_3(i, y) = \int_0^y e^{-ix} \left( 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} \right)^{i-1} \, dx?
$$

Assume that $y>0$ is bounded away from $0$. Then, by $(8.11.12)$ and  $(8.11.7)$, we have
$$
{\rm e}^i i^{ - i} \Gamma (i,i) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2i}}}  - \frac{1}{{3i}} + \frac{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}{{24i^{3/2} }} - \frac{4}{{135i^2 }} + \frac{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}{{576i^{5/2} }} + \frac{8}{{2835i^3 }} +  \ldots ,
$$
and
$$
{\rm e}^i i^{ - i} \Gamma (i,i(y + 1)) \sim (y + 1)^i {\rm e}^{ - iy} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - i)^k a_k (y)}}{{(iy)^{2k + 1} }}} ,
$$
as $i\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg i|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$). Here, $a_0(y)=1$ and
$$
a_k (y) =  - y(1 + y)a'_{k - 1} (y) + (2k - 1)(1 + y)a_{k - 1} (y)
$$
for $k\ge 1$.
Regarding the general case, $I_k (i,y)$ can be expressed as
$$
I_k (i,y) = y\int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{ - if_k (x,y)} g_k (x,y)\,{\rm d}x} ,
$$
where
$$
f_k (x,y) = yx - \log \left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {y^i \frac{{x^j }}{{j!}}} } \right),\quad g_k (x,y) = \left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {y^i \frac{{x^j }}{{j!}}} } \right)^{ - 1} .
$$
The function $f_k(x, y)$ has a unique saddle point at the origin of order $k$, with
$$
f_k (x,y) = y^{k + 1} \frac{{x^{k + 1} }}{{(k + 1)!}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {x^{k + 2} } \right)
$$
as $x \to 0^+$ for fixed $y > 0$. Using the general Laplace method, you can derive the complete asymptotic expansion for $I_k(i, y)$ as $i \to +\infty$.
